# Buttons in a fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this fragment that inflates an activity with buttons. How do I make the buttons go to another activity or fragment? the button 1 is supposed to go to a map activity and the button 2 a listfragment

EDIT**
All I want is one activity with 2 buttons and one of the buttons go to a fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //context = getApplicationContext();
        Button test= (Button)findViewById(R.id.testbtn);
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
      {
               public void onClick(View v) 
               {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyLocation.class);//this works
                   startActivity(intent);

               }
  });

        Button proximityAlert= (Button)findViewById(R.id.alertbtn);
        proximityAlert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
      {
               public void onClick(View v) 
               {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, mfragment.class);//this doesn't work, this class is a fragment list
                   startActivity(intent);

               }
  });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

mfragment class

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

public class mfragment extends ListFragment {
    String[] cities = {
            "hello",


    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setting the adapter to the layout
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cities));

    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //displays a toest of the selected item in the list 
        //using an array to and using the position of the selected item
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
            "You have selected " + cities[position], 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String selectedCity = cities[position];

        /*//cheks if the detailfragment is in the current activity
        DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment) 
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);


        //---if the detail fragment is not in the current activity as myself---
        if (detailFragment != null && detailFragment.isInLayout()) {
            //---the detail fragment is in the same activity as the master---
            detailFragment.setSelectedCity(selectedCity);
            //calls the method set selected city and sends a string with the selcted city
        } else {
        */
            //---the detail fragment is in its own activity---
            //this is only needed if is in portrait mode
            //starts a new activity and it pass arguments to know
            //which city got selected
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("city", selectedCity);
            startActivity(intent);
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the buttons in the correct layouts. If you want one button to be in the activity, you need to specify it in the activity's layout xml file. You will then use it from the activity's code. Likewise, you need to specify the button you want to be in the fragment in the fragment's xml layout file.

You cannot mix the layouts from activity and fragment, each one functions independent of each other and doesn't have direct access to each other.

Comment: What I said still stands. If you want a button on a fragment, you need to define it there.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry to say this, but you are way far from what you want. Check this example: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example

Comment: This could make a good comment but is not a good answer. It contains only a link and no explanation.